# asp.net my list is disappearing on postback - can't find what I'm missing?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, postback

This is probably an easy one, but I can't figure it out.  argh...

C# asp.net application with a custom user control.  My custom control is a simple list of images wrapped in a link to be used as a navigation tool for the parent page.

When I click a link, it does a postback: my click event does not seem to fire, and when the page reloads, the list of images disappears.

I have `EnableViewState="true"` in both the parent page and the custom control.  It is my understanding that this would be enough to preserve my list of options?  If I reload the list each time and rebind my event handler, I would think then that the event would be lost, correct?

Here is (abbreviated code) where I add the controls to my panel.

```
    public void LoadMediaOptions() {

      loop through a datareader {

        LinkButton b = new LinkButton();
        b.Click += new EventHandler(navOption_Click);
        b.Attributes.Add("mediaID", mediaID.ToString());

        HtmlImage i = new HtmlImage();
        i.Src = strThumbLink;
        i.Width = 120;
        i.Height = 90;
        b.Controls.Add(i);

        _loadedMediaHtml.Add(b);
        panMediaOptions.Controls.Add(b);
     }
  }
```

This method is currently only being called once in the parent page in the Page_Load method:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {        
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
      uxMediaNav.LoadMediaOptions();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    throw ex;
  }
}
```

After the page posts-back, there are no media options loaded for me.  My understanding of the EnableViewState is that it would preserve the elements I have loaded dynamically, but this is not the case.

Comment: please post your code... it'll really help us diagnose.

Comment: done.

As a lark, actually, I just took the LoadMediaOptions() method outside of the conditional, and my code works as expected, with the media options loading correctly, but more importantly so does the event handler, which I totally don't understand.  If the media options are cleared, and then have to be loaded manually each time, including rebinding the event handler, then how does the server figure out how to call the event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are constructing your controls too late in the page life cycle. ViewState is loaded after init and before Load. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) for the page life cycle.

This means that your custom control is unable to persist any state as the controls do not yet exist when load state occurs. Move your control construction to PreInit and it should work.

Control events fire after Load but before onLoadComplete. The event is actually passed in the request and matched to a control based on ID. Provided the control can be found by the time control events are triggered then the event will fire. Hence events generally do not rely on ViewState, with the exception of change events. Change events do because ASP.NET needs to be able to compare the original value persisted in ViewState with the current request value in order to know whether to fire the event.

To ensure any change events fire you again need to make sure the controls within your custom control are created on PreInit.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, and explains the weird behaviour I see.  I will review the article you sent - thanks!

Comment: On my main page, within the PreInit event handler, my custom user control is not created yet to do any processing.  It only exists within the Init event handler.

Comment: This problem seems to extend to private variables I want persisted as well.  They all reset to null or default values during postback.  But only for a custom control.  I have other normal controls on the page that work as expected.

Comment: Looks like I answered my own question.  I didn't realize that we were required to add/remove values to ViewState manually.  Somehow, I thought ASP.Net codemagically persisted the values that were required.  So it's not an issue of timing, but rather, I never stored anything in the ViewState for it to be saved across the PostBack.  Mystery solved.

THanks for pointing me in the direction of the page life cycle... it got me reading about ViewState and how it actually works.

Comment: When I was talking about events, I meant the events in your custom control (not the page). Adding controls to your custom control on Init is fine, I can't remember off-hand if controls have a PreInit (suspect not). ASP.NET Controls have codemagic for ViewState, but yes if you want to persist properties in your custom control you need to add to ViewState yourself. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple: put the changeControl in the Page_Load method.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        changeControl((UserControl)LoadControl("~/user-control.ascx"));
    }
```